# Inheritence method call design issue

Tags: oop, smalltalk, pharo

I'm in a bit of a pickle with designing an OO application using Pharo.

I have a class `Household`, this class has an attribute named `tvConnection`. This object is an instance of either `Digital` or `Analog`. Both these classes inherit from the super named `TVSubscription`.

If I want to add a television to my analog cable subscription I can simply call `addTV: aTelevision` on my `tvConnection` property, which will then properly call the `addTV:` method I have implemented in my `Analog` class.

A digital connection can not have televisions connected. These have to be `SetTopBox` devices, which in turn can have a television connected to them.

Now, I have to throw an error/show some output in case a user tries to add a television to a household which has a digital connection.

I figure I can do two things:

1)
I can implement the addTV: method in the `Digital` class, which will simply perform the action wanted (eg. show a message "YOU CAN NOT DO THIS!"). But this seems wrong in so many ways..

2)
I can just not implement the method and catch the `MessageNotUnderstood` error that gets thrown.
This would happen when I do the following:

```
**Adding a TV**
--> call `addTelevision` in `Household`
----> this `addTV:` on the `tvConnection` property
----> catch error if any, which implies that a TV was being added to a digital connection
```

Both of these solutions look REALLY dirty to me.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I'd probably implement `addTV:` in digital which would either add TV to a box or say that box is missing.

This looks quite nice. Think about it like:

```
TVSubscription>>addTV: aTV
  self subclassResponsibility

TVSubscription>>tvs
  self subclassResponsibility
```

`Analog` has `tvs` var.

```
Analog>>addTV: aTV
  tvs add: aTV

Analog>>tvs
  ^ tvs
```

`Digital` has `box` var.

```
Digital>>box: aBox
  box := aBox

Digital>>box
  ^ box

Digital>>addTV: aTV
  box 
    ifNil: [ Exception signal: 'Connect box' ]
    ifNotNil: [ box addTV: aTV ]

Digital>>tvs
  ^ box tvs
```

This is just a first best thought. Now I'll go to sleep and maybe I'll dream about some better solution

Comment: I think I'm going for this approach. This seems pretty straightforward. The only issue I have with this expandability. I would have to implement a `Analog >> addSetTopBox` method as well (to show the message "cant add settopbox to analog connection"). Suppose I implement another type of connection, say `Sattelite` which allows `SatSetTopBox` devices with 1 or 0 TV objects. This means I would have to implement an `addSatSetTopBox` method to all objects. This seems wrong to me?

Comment: why do you need to differentiate so much? Make a method `addAdapter:`. And then let classes to decide if they can work with this adapters or not. Also you can be even less restrictive. E.i. allow to connect whatever adapter there is. But things will begin to crumble when one adapter won't understand messages meant for other one. I'd say it's nice to put things on higher level of abstraction. So you can have adapter. And then each subscription should know what adapters it can use and how to talk with them

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should rethink your design. In my opinion the `tvConnection` should be a connection object, let's say `TVConnection`. `TVConnection` could have two subclasses `DirectConnection` and `SetTopBoxConnection`. `Digital` and `Analog` would know their connection type and the connection type knows how to `addTV:` or more conveniently, `Digital` and `Analog` implement `addTV:` and simply delegate to their `TVConnection` object.